# Printing in R studio with sprintf() does work, but not when inside a for loop?

Tags: r

This works all the time when pasted into the command line separately withOUT for loop:

```
 sprintf("Your maximum allowed investment for a period of %g years in the first year equals  %g", current_nr_of_years, max_invest_year_zero_vec[current_nr_of_years])
```

This does not print any output when run in the for loop from the script file... :

```
loop_index_vec
for (current_nr_of_years in loop_index_vec) {
  
  sprintf("Your maximum allowed investment for a period of %g years in the first year equals  %g", current_nr_of_years, max_invest_year_zero_vec[current_nr_of_years])
  # browser()
}
```

Comment: You need to `wrap` with `print` or `cat` as `sprintf` have a return value unlike `print`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference in `print` and `sprintf` is in the `return` value.  According to `?sprintf`

> A wrapper for the C function sprintf, that **returns** a character vector containing a formatted combination of text and variable values.

where as in `?print`

> print prints its argument and **returns** it invisibly (via invisible(x)).

If we want to `print` in a for loop wrap the `sprintf` in a `print` or `cat` or `message`

```
for (current_nr_of_years in loop_index_vec) {
  
  print(sprintf("Your maximum allowed investment for a period of %g years in the first year equals  %g", current_nr_of_years, max_invest_year_zero_vec[current_nr_of_years]))
  # browser()
}
```